# Qt6 circular gauge issue

Tags: qt, qml, gauge

I am developing a qml app in qt5 with circular gauge. I want to port application qt 6. But in qt 6 qtquick extras is missing, so circular gauge is not available. Is qt planning to make it available in next releases of qt6? What can I do instead of using circular gauge in qt6?
Is there anyone who knows about it?

Comment: I think you have to create it yourself. Try making it using a dashed Shape.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no plans yet to port it to Qt 6. You could create a suggestion on [Jira](https://bugreports.qt.io) to express your interest in having it.

The code is [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/extras) and [here](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Base) if you want to try to port it yourself or just use parts of it (keeping in mind the license, which is LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the question, CircularGauge is not available in Qt6. So what can you do?

As a minimal effort, you can substitute CircularGauge with a functional similar component, for instance, RangeSlider. Of course, a RangeSlider looks nothing like a CircularGauge, but, it will, at least, allow you to compile and run your application. It will give you an application to test whilst you decide your options.

Then, as others have stated, you need to spend more effort allocated to porting. If you refer to the source code of CircularGauge, you see that they're using Canvas with a custom onPaint implementation. You could do the same in your port, or, you can find an alternative, e.g. Shape with ShapePath, etc. These efforts are non-trivial, and it boils down to the level of effort you wish to invest.